# Reacte Native Debugging with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, react-native, webstorm

I've followed all [steps here in order to debug RN app using WebStorm](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/12/developing-mobile-apps-with-react-native-in-webstorm/).

First time all worked: Chrome was opened and I was able to set breakpoints on WebStorm and to actual debug some code.

When I hit the debug button again on WebStorm, I got an error:

> can't run debugger

I guess this is due to the fact that Chrome was not opened this time `localhost:8081/debugger-ui`

Since then tried much stuff (restarting Chrome, WebStorm, my Mac..). None helped.

I've downloaded Chrome again and now again WebStorm was able to open it. And again second time did not work.

I am able to debug manually using Chrome itself, but I'd really like to use WebStorm for debugging)

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Opening Chrome beforehand isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Looks similar to [WEB-30438](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30438); the issue  is fixed, fix will likely be available in the next 2017.3.3 EAP

Comment: Anything I can do right now to make it work someone? even with manual actions

Comment: there is nothing you can do here:(